# Acceso Concurrente a un Inicio de Sesion, es recomendado utilizar Hilos?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hilos, iis

Tengo una pregunta, espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, una aplicación WEB alojada en IIS;
 el enfoque es que tengo un LogIn para los usuarios, pero el LogIn debe 
permitir que un usuario inicie sesión en el momento, por lo que si dos usuarios 
intentan acceder al sitio al mismo tiempo, solo uno debe acceder, mientras que 
el otro espera hasta que el primero está conectado. Pensé en usar hilos, con una 
declaración de lock() en la validación de inicio de sesión, pero no sé si 
es una buena práctica usar hilos en este escenario, debido a que varios usuarios 
pueden intentar iniciar sesión en al mismo tiempo, y solo uno debe acceder a la
 vez. Además, necesito tener un registro para los usuarios en el orden en que
 han accedido al sitio, para verificar que dos usuarios no accedieron al mismo 
tiempo.

¿Multithreading es una buena práctica o recomendación para hacer esto?
 ¿Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio, primeramente te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio. En cuanto a la realización de preguntas es **muy importante revisar [ask]**, esto para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas excelente respuestas, saludos.

Comment: asp.net de por sí ya usa diferentes hilos para los diferentes accesos por los usuarios. No hay necesidad de crear mas hilos. Pero lo veo bien raro de que limites el acceso a un usuario a la vez. Eso es lo contrario de lo que se busca usualmente.

Comment: Te refieres a que solo un usuario debe estar conectado a la vez? Si es así tu problema no tiene nada que ver con hilos, lo que necesitas es almacenar en la base de datos o en memoria del servidor si es que ya hay un usuario conectado en el momento y actuar de acuerdo a ello.

Comment: No precisamente, pueden haber varios conectados, pero por ejemplo, al intentar iniciar sesion dos al mismo tiempo uno ingresa y el otro se queda en espera hasta que el otro ya ha ingresado, luego ya estarian los dos conectados, iniciando sesion uno despues del otro. Gracias por comentar.

Comment: Entiendo, puede que no tenga sentido, lo que pasa es que es una tarea cuyo proposito  es demostrar como funciona el multithreading, gracias.

Comment: Para multithreading te recomendaria mejor un ejemplo con sockets o comunicacion serial, o crear un servidor web teniendo un hilo escuchando los requests y con cada request crearas un hilo para atenderla y no generar un cuello de botella cuando recibas requests concurrentes.